# checking two different numbers modulos to 0 at the same time(Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a program to print out a console log statement if a number 1 - 20 is divisible by 3, 5, or both. This is what I'm using, but it wont check both numbers....

```
for (i = 1; i < 21 ; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    } else if ((i % 5)&&(i % 3) === 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    } else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

I tried searching for this, but I think my search criteria was not well stated. 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

You've got a typo in the third comparison.  It should be this:

```
else if ((i % 5) === 0 &&(i % 3) === 0)
```

Also, that comparison has to be first, otherwise it gets short-circuited by the other two.

```
if (i % 5 === 0 && i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
} else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
} // ...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbvrj/)

Comment: that is still returning Fizz and not FizzBuzz

Comment: @NathanRensen see my update -- I didn't notice at first, but the order of the if/else has to be changed.

Comment: Did you see his last comment about it being first?

Comment: I didn't, posted before. thank you, going to plug it in right now!

Answer (score 1):

first check both

```
for (i = 1; i < 21 ; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 == 0) {
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    }else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
    }else {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (i = 1; i < 21 ; i++) {
       if ((i % 5)==0 && (i % 3) == 0) {
           console.log("Fizz"); 
       } else if (i % 5 === 0) { 
           console.log("Buzz"); 
       } else if (i % 3 === 0)  { 
           console.log("FizzBuzz"); 
       } else { 
           console.log(i); 
       }
```

The one that sees if both are applicable needs to be first, otherwise it will never be met.

And you need to evaluate that condition as: (i % 5) == 0 && (i % 3) == 0

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- Checking `(x && y) === 0` is not the same as checking `(x === 0) && (y === 0)`
- You have to put the third condition first, otherwise it will never be reached

Code:

```
for (i = 1; i < 21 ; i++) {
  if ((i % 5 === 0) && (i % 3 === 0)) {
    console.log("FizzBuzz");
  } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
    console.log("Fizz");
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log("Buzz");
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```